# NestJS - How to use RoleGuard with JWT?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

Currently, I've managed to use AuthGuard with JWT authentication, but I'm not managing to get the `user` on `Roles`.

I've tried to follow the cats [example](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/sample/01-cats-app/src/common/guards/roles.guard.ts#L14), but I never get the `user` object defined, you can see on line 14.

This is my code:

```
// auth.controller.ts
@Controller('auth')
@UseGuards(RolesGuard)
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  @Get('token')
  async createToken(): Promise<any> {
    return await this.authService.createToken();
  }

  @Post()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard())
  @Roles('admin')
  findAll() {
    // this route is restricted by AuthGuard
    // JWT strategy
    return 'Super important info';
  }
}


// auth.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [SharedModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        secretOrPrivateKey: configService.get('SECRET_KEY'),
        signOptions: {
          expiresIn: configService.get('SECRET_KEY_EXPIRES'),
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    JwtStrategy,
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

All the rest is exactly as the example on the repository. Any idea how to be able to get the `users` defined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `AuthGuard()` has to run before the `RolesGuard` so that you are authenticated and the `user` property is set.

As far as I know there is no other way to change the order of your guards other then defining them as:

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard(), RolesGuard)
```

There is a discussion about a potential API for changing the exeuction hierarchy of guards in this [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/767).

---

This [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/787#issuecomment-398399162) mentions an alternative solution:

> for this use case, i feel like putting authentication logic in a middleware would be better, as it runs before the guard.